# Exercise 1.5 in Functional Analysis Haim Brezis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

[image]

For the third question, the author writes as follows:
[image]

I want to know how to deduce $F_{n_0}=E$ from $\mathrm{Int}F_{n_0}\neq\emptyset$. Thank you!

Comment: It is a *subspace* containing an open ball (thus a ball centered at 0; thus the whole space).

Comment: Why must the ball be centered at $0$?

Comment: The proclaimed set might not be, but you can take a translation of it that is.

Comment: So, let $O$ be a non-empty open ball in that interior and look at $O-a$, where $a$ is the center of $O$.